# JBOSS EAP and SPRING: Issues with spring-jdbc ns

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jboss-eap-6, jboss-developer-studio

I a project I use spring jdbc:embedded-database xml config for JUNIT tests. The spring version is 4.3.3.RELEASE.
When i try to configure in xml spring-jdbc in JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1.GA i got the following issue:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is       not .
>     - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jdbc:embedded-database'.

The failing configuration is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

  ...
  <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />
```

Instead, using

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">
```

JBoss Developer Studio doesn't  give errors.

Also, I note that the error comes up ONLY from JBoss Developer Studio UI, if I launch tests from maven (or install) I don't have any error.

How can I solve this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no JBoss EAP 7.1.1. Are you using JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I refer to JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1.GA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JBoss has some problems finding the xsd file inside war/jar.

The workaround are specific to JBoss, details here if you have some Redhat account (I don't) :

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2381041
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/62251

Comment: Thanks, I got the RedHat account but I'm not a subscriber of the service so I can't access...